# SQL query to produce month report status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
TICKET ID | OPEN DATE  | CLOSE DATE
----------+------------+------------
1         | 2018-12-30 | 2019-01-01 
2         | 2019-01-30 | 2019-02-01 
3         | 2019-01-20 | 2019-01-22
```

I have to produce a view that create for each ticket id several entry with a status (OPEN, CLOSED, BACKLOG), for each month of the current year. Status OPEN if OPEN DATE is in the month, status CLOSED if closed date is in the month, BACKLOG if the open date was in the previous month and close date was not in the previous month.

So in the example below the output table would be:

```
TICKET ID | MONTH  | STATUS
----------+--------+---------
1         | JAN-19 | BACKLOG
1         | JAN-19 | CLOSED
2         | JAN-19 | OPEN
3         | JAN-19 | OPEN
3         | JAN-19 | CLOSED
2         | FEB-19 | CLOSED
```

Is there a way to do that in pure SQL in SQL Server?

Comment: If you want each month of the current year, why do your sample results show only one month?

Comment: Hi I edit the question. I forgot just one month because for the other months there is no entry with this examples. And also it would make sense to produce data for each month of the year till the current month.

Comment: For TICKET ID = 2 OPEN DATE and CLOSE DATE are in different months, why not BACKLOG? Also what is the condition for the 2 column dates? Do you want to query all the CLOSE DATEs of 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description suggests:

```
    select t.ticket_id, v.mon, v.status
    from t cross apply
         (values ('OPEN', datefromparts(year(open_date), month(open_date), 1)),
                 ('CLOSED', datefromparts(year(open_date), month(open_date), 1)),
                 ('BACKLOG', datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, 1, open_date)), month(dateadd(month, 1, open_date)), 1))
        ) v(status, mon)
where status <> 'BACKLOG' or
      datediff(month, open_date, close_date) > 0;
```

You can add filtering in the `where` clause for a particular period of time, such as dates in 2019.

This should do exactly what you want for "BACKLOG":

> BACKLOG if the open date was in the previous month and close date was not in the previous month.

However, you have not taken multiple months of backlog into account.  If this is a possibility, ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?  You can adjust the period it runs over by tweaking the dates table.

```
declare @tickets table (ticketId int, openDate datetime, closeDate datetime)

insert into @tickets (ticketId, openDate, closeDate) values (1, '30 Dec 2018', '1 Jan 2019')
insert into @tickets (ticketId, openDate, closeDate) values (2, '30 Jan 2019', '1 Feb 2019')
insert into @tickets (ticketId, openDate, closeDate) values (3, '20 Jan 2019', '22 Jan 2019')

; with dates as (
    select cast('1 Jan 2019' as datetime) startMon, cast('31 Jan 2019' as dateTime) endMon
    union all
    select dateAdd(mm, 1, startMon), DATEADD(dd, -1, dateAdd(mm, 2, startMon)) from dates where startMon < '01 Dec 2019'
)
select ticketId, startMon, 'BACKLOG' [Status] from @tickets t inner join dates d on t.openDate between dateAdd(m, -1, startMon) and startMon and closeDate < endMon and closeDate >= startMon
union
select ticketId, startMon, 'OPEN' from @tickets t inner join dates d on t.openDate between startMon and endMon
union
select ticketId, startMon, 'CLOSED' from @tickets t inner join dates d on t.closeDate between startMon and endMon
order by startMon, ticketId
```